# Вложенные JOIN с GROUP BY

Tags: sql, sql-server

Возникла у меня тут творческая проблема: нужно создать несколько JOIN'ов с вложенными подзапросами в одном запросе да так, чтоб каждый последующий JOIN ссылался на результат подзапроса из предыдущего JOIN'а. Выглядеть эта странная конструкция должна примерно так:

```sql
select a1.id, a2.param1, a3.param2, a4.param3 from sometable a1
inner join
(select id, max(param1) as param1 from a1 group by id) a2
on (a2.id=a1.id and a2.param1=a1.param1)
inner join
(select id, max(param2) as param2 from a2 group by id) a3
on (a3.id=a1.id and a3.param2=a2.param2)
inner join
(select id, max(param3) as param3 from a3 group by id) a4
on (a4.id=a1.id and a4.param2=a3.param2)
order by id
```

Однако, SQL, увы, не дает мне ссылаться из выборки, скажем, с алиасом a4 на результат выборки с алиасом a3. Полученного результата я могу, конечно, добиться, создав 3 вьюшки, ссылающиеся последовательно одна на другую, но это будет, мягко говоря, не самым элегантным решением.
Как бы это покрасивше реализовать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Используйте [Common Table Expressions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766(v=sql.105).aspx) - это, практически, "внешние" именованные подзапросы. Из из CTE можно ссылаться на другие CTE, объявленные выше):

```sql
WITH 
a2 AS
 (select id, max(param1) as param1 from a1 group by id),
a3 AS
 (select id, max(param2) as param2 from a2 group by id),
a4 AS
 (select id, max(param3) as param3 from a3 group by id)

select a1.id, a2.param1, a3.param2, a4.param3 from sometable a1
inner join a2
  on (a2.id=a1.id and a2.param1=a1.param1)
inner join a3
  on (a3.id=a1.id and a3.param2=a2.param2)
inner join a4
  on (a4.id=a1.id and a4.param2=a3.param2)
order by id
```

Comment: отлично! похоже, именно то, что нужно!

Answer (score 2):

Вам не нужен СТЕ в данном случае.

> Однако, SQL, увы, не дает мне ссылаться из выборки, скажем, с алиасом a4 на результат выборки с алиасом a3

От чего же? В данном случае СТЕ всё равно подставятся во FROM как обычные подзапросы.
Кроме косметики никакой пользы от СТЕ нет. Вот простой пример, где работают подзапросы.

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.param1, a3.param3, a4.param3
FROM
 (SELECt 1 Id, 1 param1)a1
 INNER JOIN (SELECt 1 Id, 1 param1, 2 param2)a2
 ON (a1.Id = a2.Id AND a1.param1 = a2.param1)
 INNER JOIN (SELECt 1 Id, 2 param2, 3 param3)a3
 ON (a1.Id = a3.Id AND a2.param2 = a3.param2)
 INNER JOIN (SELECt 1 Id, 3 param3)a4
 ON (a1.Id = a4.Id AND a3.param3 = a4.param3)
```

А у вас скорее всего была ошибка синтаксиса.
В частности, в вашем примере в подзапросе a4 отсутствует столбец с именем param2, но вы пытаетесь его использовать в условии соединения.

**upd:**

Другое дело, если вам **внутри подзапроса** надо ссылаться на результат **предыдущего подзапроса**. Тогда вам может помочь оператор APPLY:

```
SELECT a1.id, a2.param1, a3.param3, a4.param3
FROM
  (SELECt 1 Id, 1 param1)a1
  CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT *
    FROM(SELECt 1 Id, 1 param1, 2 param2)a2
    WHERE a1.Id = a2.Id AND a1.param1 = a2.param1
  )a2
  CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT *
    FROM(SELECt 1 Id, 2 param2, 3 param3)a3
    WHERE a1.Id = a3.Id AND a2.param2 = a3.param2
  )a3
  CROSS APPLY(
    SELECT *
    FROM(SELECt 1 Id, 3 param3)a4
    WHERE a1.Id = a4.Id AND a3.param3 = a4.param3
  )a4
```